# Mac documents replaced by iCloud documents

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

Something strange happened, my documents (local to my MBP) have been replaced by my iCloud documents. I don't know how and when this happened.

Is there any way I can check how and when it happened and can restore it? I do not have a Time Machine backup

Comment: Can you clarify which folder you were looking at  ? What did you do before you think it happened? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/288622/313842 is this helpful. ?

Comment: Try looking at your iCloud sync log with the command `syslog -d /var/log/com.apple.clouddocs.asl/`. It will list all events related to logins, config updates and syncs.  Let me know what your results are

Comment: ***Close voters*** - this question is quite clear; the OP is asking *how* to find when when something happened and if there can be a restore.  Both answerable with the existing info!

Comment: Are you saying that a folder (which?) on your hard drive used to contain some ("local") files, which are now gone, and different files, which were in your iCloud Drive, are now in their place? Or older versions of the same files? Or something else? Do you use iCloud Documents & Desktop syncing? Finally: if you don't have a backup, then it's very easy to lose files forever.

Comment: @Allan no such file or directory

Comment: @Allan some ppl like to abuse the power of close of SE

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @Allan Mojave. I updated the tag as well

Comment: Thanks.  It's a different command now  - `log` - but I'll have to get you the full command to try a little later today because I'm away from my Mac and my iPad just doesn't do Unix commands.

Comment: @Allan still waiting for your answer

Comment: @Allan I tried removing icloud documents and desktop, which made my local document and desktop come back but empty. But why does it happened e.g. why iCloud replaced my desktop and document with iCloud?